# How to save results from `wholeTextFile` RDD using `saveATextFile` in spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark

I have created many files in HDFS using spark in a `wholeTextFile` RDD, and I'd like to be able to save them in a particular directory using

```
anRDD.saveAsTextFile(<directory_path>)
```

The problem with this is that it will try to create an entirely new directory.  I just want to place these results in an existing directory.  How do I do this?

I've checked out the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=rdd#pyspark.RDD.saveAsTextFile), but the `path` parameter doesn't seem to change anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Roll your own `saveAsTextFile` implementation that doesn't check if the output directory exists already.
2. Write to a temp folder, then move the files to your existing directory.

---

`RDD.saveAsTextFile` uses `TextOutputFormat`, a Hadoop `OutputFormat`, to write results.  If you look at the implementation of `TextOutputFormat` and its base class `FileOutputFormat`, there is no option to overwrite or append to an existing directory.  This makes sense as it would need to come up with unique file names for every output part.

Comment: That does not make sense to me, since `HIVE` tables work by creating many files of different names in a directory for a particular table.  So if `HIVE` can do it, why not `hadoop`?  and if `hadoop` then why not `spark`?

Comment: Hive has additional logic to handle this use case.  Hadoop and Spark do not.  It's not a matter of `can` or `can't`, just whether it's implemented or not.